# the meaning of "hits primetime"

Tags: meaning

[From a tutorial](https://youtu.be/FWdtXZJGPQk)

"February 9th, 1964. Beatlemania hits primetime in the United States."

I understand every single word in the sentence.

Beatlemania means a group of enthusiastic fans of Beatles.

primetime refers to the time when television audience is expected to be at its highest, such as 8 o'clock PM, when most people are watching TV at home.

I also know the Beatles made first U.S. TV appearance on 'Ed Sullivan Show' On Feb. 9, 1964.

what is the meaning of "Beatlemania hits primetime"?

---

How about this explanation,

> the enthusiasm for the Beatles arrived at a stage where there are more influential people recognize them?

Comment: You explained you understanding of *most* of those words, but what about *hit*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here "Beatlemania" doesn't mean a group of fans, but the phenomenon of their existence, "a  mania":

[American Heritage Dictionary "-mania"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=mania) 
(suffix) An exaggerated desire or enthusiasm for  e.g. *"balletomania"*

[American Heritage Dictionary "hit"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=hit)
a. Informal To go to or arrive at: *We hit the beach early.*

So it means, roughly, the enthusiasm for the Beatles arrived

I think "primetime" can be read as a noun meaning the destination of the arrival. It might also be an adverb, meaning the time of arrival, but it doesn't make any difference to the import of the sentence.

Comment: Thank you. How about this explanation,  the enthusiasm for the Beatles arrived at a stage where there are more influential people recognize them?

Comment: No, I wouldn't put it that way. It's not "influential people", but the a great mass of ordinary people. "Primetime" basically means television air time in the evening, when great numbers of people can see it.

Comment: The show's host, Ed Sullivan, was influential, wasn't he?

Comment: Yes, but the millions of people watching TV who were the audience for  primetime TV were ordinary people.

Comment: And, please don't edit my name into your question as if I suggested your interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

I would interpret it as "the phenomenon of intense enthusiasm for the Beatles was exposed to a mass audience".

Beatlemania was not "a group of fans", but the astonishing behaviour of those fans: intense screaming, fainting, crying etc.

Primetime is literally that timeslot, but by extension, the widest possible television audience.

Hence: this was the moment when millions of people watching TV saw for the first time how young people (particularly women) behaved as a response to watching the Beatles.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the passionate enthusiasm for the Beatles was regarded as of such importance that the Beatles were deemed a worthy subject for primetime TV, which, because of the number of viewers, tended to be time for matters of broad and serious interest.

Artistically, calling something "ready for primetime" denotes something that was polished and ready for a general audience, as opposed to a special audience that would overlook flaws because of special interest in it.